# Postgres function for updating table b when a column in table a is updated

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am new to postgres triggers and functions and I am currently having an issue with setting up a trigger on table A to update table B when a boolean column in table A is switches from true to false or vice versa.

Table B is a "mapping" table that has values from Table A / Table B and other tables that don't have any reliable means of linkage and thus I am creating triggers to propagate data to this mapping table.

Trigger and Trigger function below:

```
--TRIGGER FUNCTION TO UPDATE CCM AFTER ENVIRONMENT TYPE IS CHANGED
--  THIS SHOULD BE A TRIGGER BASED FUNCTION - NO INPUT WILL BE PASSED
--  THIS WILL NEED TO BE DONE POST UPDATE ON THE RECORD
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION live.ccmu4statust()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    CASE WHEN TG_ARGV[0] = 'true' THEN
      UPDATE live.customer_control_mapping set enabled = true where customer_env_name = TG_ARGV[0];
    ELSE
      UPDATE live.customer_control_mapping set enabled = false where customer_env_name = TG_ARGV[0];
    END CASE;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--TRIGGER ON LIVE.CUSTOMER_SPEC
--  SHOULD ONLY EXECUTE WHEN A CUSTOMER_ENV_STATUS IS UPDATED
-- RESULTED IN A CASTING ISSUE FOR BOOLEAN VALUE
CREATE TRIGGER ccmu4statusJello
AFTER UPDATE
ON live.customer_spec
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE live.ccmu4statust('customer_env_name','customer_enabled');

The error that I am getting is:
Error: ERROR: control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
  Where: PL/pgSQL function live.ccmu4statust()
SQLState:  2F005
ErrorCode: 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Please note the mapping table is required for development functionality and I can't remove it, hence I need the updates working.

A manual function worked for me (it is below) - it was done as a test.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION live.ccmu4status(custEnvName text,customer_enabled boolean)
  RETURNS VOID AS $$
  BEGIN
     UPDATE live.customer_control_mapping set customer_enabled = $2 where customer_env_name = $1;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Thanks again and have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you need to do is the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION live.ccmu4statust() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.env_status != OLD.env_status THEN
        UPDATE live.customer_control_mapping
        SET enabled = NEW.env_status
        WHERE customer_env_name = NEW.env_name;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ccmu4statusJello
AFTER UPDATEON live.customer_spec
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE live.ccmu4statust();
```

In trigger functions you can make use of the implicitly defined variables `OLD` and `NEW` which represent the original and the updated row, respectively. Trigger functions always require a `RETURN` statement; you should usually `RETURN NEW` to make the update succeed (although this here is an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger so you could also just `RETURN` but better to be consistent).

Note also that this trigger function uses data from columns in table `live.customer_spec` only, so no environmental variables are used (which seems to be the case in your code). Much cleaner and much easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and after about 10 mins realizing I was looking at the wrong field I realized the above solution worked.. Thanks Again!